# How to change this method into @auraEnable method

Tags: aura-enabled

```
public PageReference back() {
    PageReference pgRef = new PageReference('/' + oppId);

    return pgRef;
}
```

Comment: ...by adding the `@auraEnabled` annotation on the line above the method signature?

Comment: @AuraEnabled
    public static string back(){
       '/'+ oppId
       return;
    }

Comment: I tried like this

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Instead of adding them as comments, please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/367810/edit) your question to add these and any future additional things that you have tried (please don't edit the original code in the question - that can cause confusion for future readers). It makes it easier for people trying to help you to see all the information in the question. Some people add **Update** at the bottom of their question, and then add new information there.

Answer (score 4):

Navigation in Aura and LWC is done with [force:navigateToUrl](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToURL/documentation) and [NavigationMixin](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-navigation/documentation). There's usually no need to get Apex involved at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can try as @sfdcfox suggested using either methods, or in your JS can also try to redirect the user using window.open(location to redirect);